# MongoDB: is there a way to tweak the output?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

For the following command:

```
db.my_items.aggregate({
    $match: {
        // ...
    }
},{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        myField: 1
    }
}).result.forEach(function(obj) {
    print(obj.myField)
})
```

Is there a way to perform the `forEach` from inside the `aggregate` query?

Comment: What would you want the foreach to achieve within the query? I seems like you are outputting exactly what you are doing, you cannot print to screen from the query.

Comment: @Sammaye just because I would like to enjoy from returning the data in the exactly right format, to make the `forEach` loop redundant

Comment: Unfortunately atm the return MUST be a BSON document so even if you could put that foreach into the query itself it would have to return the "return" as BSON document which would need a foreach in turn.

Comment: @Sammaye I could mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due the way MongoDB responds what you want to do is not possible. MongoDB accepts input and responds with BSON documents, and that is in fact the return you are getting here.

Since MongoDB requires a BSON document return even if you could put the `forEach` into the query itself you would need an extra foreach on the return to iterate the BSON document return.

Comment: so just for the record - what would be the proper way to "ask" mongo to return the query in the required format? Would it be ok to ask about how to utilize `mongoexport` for example? It's OK to me if not as the answer is given and thanks for that.

Comment: @BreakPhreak It depends on how you are using this, if you are using it in a application then mongoexport could be difficult but if you are using this as an admin function to get data out then mongoexport could work

Comment: Thanks! Opened the following subsequent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078215/how-to-put-the-following-through-mongoexport